# Poisson parameter in Merton's Jump-Diffusion Model to price call option

Tags: options, black-scholes, jump-diffusion, black-scholes-merton

I've been taught the following European call valuation formula under jump-diffusion model:
\begin{equation}
price = E[e^{-rT}max(S_T-K,0)] =\sum_{j = 0}^\infty e^{-rT}P_j(\lambda)E[max(S_T-K,0)|J=j]
\end{equation}
where $J$ is the number of jumps, probability term $P$ is the poisson process:
\begin{equation}
e^{-\lambda T} \frac{(\lambda T)^j}{j!} 
\end{equation}
And I've been given directly the final form of the valuation formula:
\begin{equation}
price = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty P_j(\lambda^{'})BS(S_0,r_j,\sigma_j^2)
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
\lambda^{'}=\lambda(1+k)
\end{equation}
$k$ is the average jump size, and:
\begin{equation}
r_j = r-\lambda k+j\ln(1+k) / T, \sigma_j^2=\sigma^2+j\sigma_s^2/T
\end{equation}
$\sigma^2 $ is original Black-Scholes volitility, $\sigma_s^2$ is the jump variance.

By expanding the Black-Scholes equation, I've managed to derive $r_j$ and $\sigma_j^2$, but I'm confused  about where $\lambda^{'}$ comes from. Can someone help derive this term?

In case of anything unclear, the formula can also be found [here](http://finance.bi.no/~bernt/gcc_prog/algoritms_v1/algoritms/node44.html) and [here](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Jump-Diffusion-Models-for-European-Options-Pricing-in-C) (in the second link, $m=1+k$)